# How to check command line arguments in a kdb script?

Tags: kdb

I want to check the number of command arguments in my Q script and return an error message if .z.x doesn't match the intended number of arguments. So far I came up with this line:

```
if[count .z.x < 4; '`BadUsage]
"Arguments OK"
```

I never get past the if statement, it always returns `BadUsage, regardless of the number of arguments I'm using.

How do I check for the correct number of arguments, print an error message and exit the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because the statements are evaluated right to left. So .z.x < 4 is evaluated first, and then the count of that result.

```
q)count .z.x < 4
0
q)4 > count .z.x
1b
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I print an error message, return the BadUsage code and exit the script? I haven't figured how to include multiple instructions in the if statement after the conditional evaluation.

Comment: Something like this: q)if[4 > count .z.x; 0N!"BadUsage"; exit[0]] . The problem with your statement above, is once it hits the ' , any statements after that are not evaluated.